# Why explain analyze and execution query time is different

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-10

I have a query with two tables join based on condition `b.customer_id = a.customer_id`, there is index(btree) on both table on both columns `customer_id`.

When I ran `explain analyze` it says `15 ms`:

[image]

But when I execute query it took `26 secs`:

```
Successfully run. Total query runtime: 26 secs 168 msec.
30038 rows affected.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are using pgAdmin or a similar client tool that takes a long time to render 30038 rows.

Comment: Then which time should be noted as actual query execution time? I got confused between `query execution time` in PgAdmin and `Explain Analyze Execution time`.

Comment: That depends on your use case. If your actual use case is to view 30000 with pgAdmin, take the 26 seconds. The execution time on the server cannot contain the network latency or the time it takes the client to process the result.