# Postgres query time execution varying a lot between two queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I have a table `tableA` which contains 600k rows of data (and other tables B, C, D etc...).

This simple query takes 700ms (??) to execute on PgAdmin:

```sql
select id from tableA limit 1
```

Here is the `explain` :

```
"Limit  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=1 width=93) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on tableA  (cost=0.00..16082.65 rows=619265 width=93) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 0.058 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.026 ms"
```

First question is why does it take 700ms when planning + execution time is less than 1ms? I am far away from the db, so let's assume it's a network latency issue.

Now I have this other query :

```sql
SELECT "tableA"."id" AS "tag_id", "tableA"."shortId" AS "tag_shortId", "tableA"."externalId" AS "tag_externalId", "tableA"."index" AS "tag_index", "tableA"."createdDate" AS "tag_createdDate", 
"tableA"."updatedDate" AS "tag_updatedDate", "tableA"."personId" AS "personId", "tableA"."createdById" AS "tag_createdById", "tableB"."id" AS "tableB_id", "tableB"."name" AS "tableB_name", 
"tableB"."image" AS "tableB_image", "tableB"."address" AS "tableB_address", "tableB"."city" AS "tableB_city", "tableB"."state" AS "tableB_state", "tableB"."zip" AS "tableB_zip", "tableB"."country" 
AS "tableB_country", "tableB"."capacity" AS "tableB_capacity", "tableB"."type" AS "tableB_type", "tableB"."externalURL" AS "tableB_externalURL", "tableB"."externalId" AS "tableB_externalId", 
"tableB"."createdDate" AS "tableB_createdDate", "tableB"."updatedDate" AS "tableB_updatedDate", "tableB"."tagCount" AS "tableB_tagCount", "tableB"."brandId" AS "tableB_brandId", 
"tableB"."ownerId" AS "tableB_ownerId", "tableB"."createdById" AS "tableB_createdById", "target"."id" AS "target_id", "target"."name" AS "target_name", "target"."image" AS "target_image", 
"target"."startDate" AS "target_startDate", "target"."endDate" AS "target_endDate", "target"."isPerpetual" AS "target_isPerpetual", "target"."isLive" AS "target_isLive", 
"target"."defaultExternalURL" AS "target_defaultExternalURL", "target"."externalId" AS "target_externalId", "target"."createdDate" AS "target_createdDate", "target"."updatedDate" 
AS "target_updatedDate", "target"."personId" AS "target_tableBId", "target"."totoId" AS "target_totoId", "target"."brandId" 
AS "target_brandId", "target"."createdById" AS "target_createdById" 

FROM "tableA" "tableA" 
LEFT JOIN "tag_data" "tagData" ON "tagData"."tagId"="tableA"."id"  
LEFT JOIN "tableB" "tableB" ON "tableB"."id"="tableA"."personId"  
LEFT JOIN "target" "target" ON "tableA"."personId" = "target"."personId"
AND (("target"."startDate" <= NOW() AND "target"."endDate" >= NOW()) OR "target"."isPerpetual" = true) 
LIMIT 25
```

The query itself doesn't really matter, just to show that it is a pretty big query with multiple conditional joins etc... This query runs in **400ms** compared to the first query of **700ms** (???)

Here is the query explain :

```
*doing bunch of merge and index search etc...*
"Planning Time: 0.630 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.353 ms"
```

So we can see that query 2 takes longer to execute (about 1ms) which makes sense compared to query 1.

My question is, why query 1 takes 700ms (with explain < 1ms and 1 row of data) and query 2 takes 400ms (with explain of 1ms and 25 rows of data), especially if the main reason of the 700ms is 'poor network' ?

Any help appreciated

PS: the times mentioned are averages and the DB is running on RDS with very low activity

UPDATE: [Why explain analyze and execution query time is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68212164/why-explain-analyze-and-execution-query-time-is-different) does not answer, I'm returning **1** row there not thousands of row that needs "rendering"

Comment: Well, one lists specific columns it wants, and the other does *.  For all we can tell, maybe the first one is selecting columns with megabytes of gibberish in them, and that has to be sent over the network and digested by pgAdmin.

Comment: @jjanes I change * to `id`, same 700ms