# Postgres query time execution varying a lot between two queries (not rendering issue with low results)

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I have a table `tableA` which contains 600k rows of data (and other tables B, C, D etc...).

This simple query takes 700ms (??) to execute on PgAdmin:

```sql
select id from tableA limit 1
```

Here is the `explain` :

```
"Limit  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=1 width=93) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on tableA  (cost=0.00..16082.65 rows=619265 width=93) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 0.058 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.026 ms"
```

First question is why does it take 700ms when planning + execution time is less than 1ms? I am far away from the db, so let's assume it's a network latency issue.

Now I have this other query :

```sql
SELECT "tableA"."id" AS "tag_id", "tableA"."shortId" AS "tag_shortId", "tableA"."externalId" AS "tag_externalId", "tableA"."index" AS "tag_index", "tableA"."createdDate" AS "tag_createdDate", 
"tableA"."updatedDate" AS "tag_updatedDate", "tableA"."personId" AS "personId", "tableA"."createdById" AS "tag_createdById", "tableB"."id" AS "tableB_id", "tableB"."name" AS "tableB_name", 
"tableB"."image" AS "tableB_image", "tableB"."address" AS "tableB_address", "tableB"."city" AS "tableB_city", "tableB"."state" AS "tableB_state", "tableB"."zip" AS "tableB_zip", "tableB"."country" 
AS "tableB_country", "tableB"."capacity" AS "tableB_capacity", "tableB"."type" AS "tableB_type", "tableB"."externalURL" AS "tableB_externalURL", "tableB"."externalId" AS "tableB_externalId", 
"tableB"."createdDate" AS "tableB_createdDate", "tableB"."updatedDate" AS "tableB_updatedDate", "tableB"."tagCount" AS "tableB_tagCount", "tableB"."brandId" AS "tableB_brandId", 
"tableB"."ownerId" AS "tableB_ownerId", "tableB"."createdById" AS "tableB_createdById", "target"."id" AS "target_id", "target"."name" AS "target_name", "target"."image" AS "target_image", 
"target"."startDate" AS "target_startDate", "target"."endDate" AS "target_endDate", "target"."isPerpetual" AS "target_isPerpetual", "target"."isLive" AS "target_isLive", 
"target"."defaultExternalURL" AS "target_defaultExternalURL", "target"."externalId" AS "target_externalId", "target"."createdDate" AS "target_createdDate", "target"."updatedDate" 
AS "target_updatedDate", "target"."personId" AS "target_tableBId", "target"."totoId" AS "target_totoId", "target"."brandId" 
AS "target_brandId", "target"."createdById" AS "target_createdById" 

FROM "tableA" "tableA" 
LEFT JOIN "tag_data" "tagData" ON "tagData"."tagId"="tableA"."id"  
LEFT JOIN "tableB" "tableB" ON "tableB"."id"="tableA"."personId"  
LEFT JOIN "target" "target" ON "tableA"."personId" = "target"."personId"
AND (("target"."startDate" <= NOW() AND "target"."endDate" >= NOW()) OR "target"."isPerpetual" = true) 
LIMIT 25
```

The query itself doesn't really matter, just to show that it is a pretty big query with multiple conditional joins etc... This query runs in **400ms** compared to the first query of **700ms** (???)

Here is the query explain :

```
*doing bunch of merge and index search etc...*
"Planning Time: 0.630 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.353 ms"
```

So we can see that query 2 takes longer to execute (about 1ms) which makes sense compared to query 1.

My question is, why query 1 takes 700ms (with explain < 1ms and 1 row of data) and query 2 takes 400ms (with explain of 1ms and 25 rows of data), especially if the main reason of the 700ms is 'poor network' ?

Any help appreciated

PS: the times mentioned are averages and the DB is running on RDS with very low activity

UPDATE: [Why explain analyze and execution query time is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68212164/why-explain-analyze-and-execution-query-time-is-different) does not answer, I'm returning **1** row there not thousands of row that needs "rendering"

Comment: Read this [Limit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT). I going to say you will be helped by an `ORDER BY`, especially as without one you don't really know what `id` you are going to get. If you are looking for a random `id` then use `ORDER BY random()`. As to why `pgAdmin4` is dragging it generally come down to some sort of GUI issue. What it is in this case I don't know.

Comment: Can you reproduce it without use of pgAdmin?  For example, using psql from the same host you are now running pgAdmin from?

Comment: Can you reproduce it if you put pgAdmin on an EC2 machine in the same datacenter as the RDS machine?